# Poor performance of vector<bool> in 64-bit target with VS2012

Tags: c++, performance, vector, boolean

Benchmarking this class:

```
struct Sieve {
  std::vector<bool> isPrime;

  Sieve (int n = 1) {
    isPrime.assign (n+1, true);
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= (int)sqrt((double)n); ++i)
      if (isPrime[i]) 
        for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j += i)
          isPrime[j] = false;
  }
};
```

I'm getting over 3 times worse performance (CPU time) with 64-bit binary vs. 32-bit version (release build) when calling a constructor for a large number, e.g.

```
Sieve s(100000000);
```

I tested `sizeof(bool)` and it is `1` for both versions.
When I substitute `vector<bool>` with `vector<char>` performance becomes the same for 64-bit and 32-bit versions. Why is that?

Here are the run times for `S(100000000)` (release mode, 32-bit first, 64-bit second)):

`vector<bool>` 0.97s 3.12s
`vector<char>` 0.99s 0.99s
`vector<int>`  1.57s 1.59s

I also did a sanity test with VS2010 (prompted by Wouter Huysentruit's response), which produced 0.98s 0.88s. So there is something wrong with VS2012 implementation.

I submitted a bug report to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/784973/performance-of-vector-bool-3-times-slower-in-64-bit-build-than-32-bit-build)

**EDIT**

Many answers below comment on deficiencies of using `int` for indexing. This may be true, but even the Great Wizard himself is using a standard `for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)` in his books, so such a pattern should not incur a significant performance penalty. Additionally, this issue was raised during Going Native 2013 conference and the presiding group of C++ gurus commented on their early recommendations of using `size_t` for indexing and as a return type of `size()` as a mistake. They said: "we are sorry, we were young..."

The title of this question could be rephrased to: *Over 3 times performance drop on this code when upgrading from VS2010 to VS2012.*

**EDIT**

I made a crude attempt at finding memory alignment of indexes `i` and `j` and discovered that this instrumented version:

```
struct Sieve {
  vector<bool> isPrime;

  Sieve (int n = 1) {
    isPrime.assign (n+1, true);
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt((double)n); ++i) {
      if (i == 17) cout << ((int)&i)%16 << endl;
      if (isPrime[i]) 
        for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j += i) {
          if (j == 4) cout << ((int)&j)%16 << endl;
          isPrime[j] = false;
        }
    }
  }
};
```

auto-magically runs fast now (only 10% slower than 32-bit version). This and VS2010 performance makes it hard to accept a theory of optimizer having inherent problems dealing with `int` indexes instead of `size_t`.

Comment: Debug or Release build?

Comment: There's a space-optimized `vector<bool>` template specialization, see [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool).

Comment: Notice that you can also use a more specific class: [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/)

Comment: @HugoCorrá `bitset` has a fixed size (template parameter)

Comment: @DyP, that explains why there's a difference between `vector<bool>` and `vector<char>` but doesn't explain the difference between 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, that's why it's a comment and not an answer :D

Comment: @Dyp Yes, you are right!!! So I would like to suggest the use of [boost dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)

Comment: @Sven It's a release build.

Comment: @DyP I know about more efficient implementations and I will be testing them. I would like to know what is the reason for THIS particular behavior.

Comment: @PaulJurczak What is your compiler?  Does `sizeof(unsigned int)` vary between 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: Maybe you're getting unaligned accesses 7 times out of 8 on the 64 bit version, vs 3 out of 4 on the 32 bit version (wild guess).

Comment: At the end of the day, the only way you're going to get an authoritative answer is to post a QOI bug report on [MS Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/). Afterwards, please post a link to the bug report here so we can upvote it. :-]

Comment: Please post the complete, self-contained benchmark code, the full set of options passed to the compiler, and the full versions of the compiler binaries (run `cl /Bv`).  [I tried to repro this using Visual C++ 2012 Update 1 (17.00.51106.1), with /MT /O2, and observed that the x86 and x64 builds of my test program have similar performance on my Core i7.  You are welcome to open a bug on Connect, but if you do, please post all of this information as well.]

Comment: @James McNellis I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2012 11.0.60315.01 Update 2, cl version 17.00.60315.1 with /MD /O2.

Comment: @James McNellis I submitted a bug report - see my edited question.

Comment: @GManNickG I attached it and then did it again. The site is super slow for me and tells me that it may be a few hours for other users to see attachment :(

Comment: What about taking a look into the source of `std::vector<bool>`. Once you're accustomed to the ugly identifiers it isn't that hard to understand and might reveal a possible design flaw.

Comment: "*This may be true, but even the Great Wizard himself is using a standard `for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)` in his books*" This pattern is wrong, and has always been wrong – nobody's perfect.

Comment: @ildjarn Well, he is not the only one. I did a quick search through ebooks I have and even _The C++ Standard Library Second Edition_ uses this pattern on some occasions. Not mentioning billions line of C++ code out there. I'm not wedded to it and this has been a great opportunity to reexamine my coding habits. My point is that in a language with huge installed base like C++ , compiler vendors have to be very careful about not breaking widely used patterns.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've tested this with `vector<bool>` in VS2010: 32-bit needs 1452ms while 64-bit needs 1264ms to complete on a i3.

The same test in VS2012 (on i7 this time) needs 700ms (32-bit) and 2730ms (64-bit), so there is something wrong with the compiler in VS2012. Maybe you can report this test case as a bug to Microsoft.

**UPDATE**

The problem is that the VS2012 compiler uses a temporary stack variable for a part of the code in the inner for-loop when using int as iterator. The assembly parts listed below are part of the code inside `<vector>`, in the `+= operator`  of the `std::vector<bool>::iterator`.

**size_t as iterator**

When using `size_t` as iterator, a part of the code looks like this:

```
or  rax, -1
sub rax, rdx
shr rax, 5
lea rax, QWORD PTR [rax*4+4]
sub r8, rax
```

Here, all instructions use CPU registers which are very fast.

**int as iterator**

When using `int` as iterator, that same part looks like this:

```
or  rcx, -1
sub rcx, r8
shr rcx, 5
shl rcx, 2
mov rax, -4
sub rax, rcx
mov rdx, QWORD PTR _Tmp$6[rsp]
add rdx, rax
```

Here you see the _Tmp$6 stack variable being used, which causes the slowdown.

**Point compiler into the right direction**

The funny part is that you can point the compiler into the right direction by using the `vector<bool>::iterator` directly.

```
struct Sieve {
  std::vector<bool> isPrime;

  Sieve (int n = 1) {
    isPrime.assign(n + 1, true);

    std::vector<bool>::iterator it1 = isPrime.begin();
    std::vector<bool>::iterator end = it1 + n;
    *it1++ = false;
    *it1++ = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= (int)sqrt((double)n); ++it1, ++i)
        if (*it1)
            for (std::vector<bool>::iterator it2 = isPrime.begin() + i * i; it2 <= end; it2 += i)
                *it2 = false;
  }
};
```

Comment: Confirmed that. My timings are: 0.88s for 64-bit and 0.98s for 32-bit version on VS2010.

Comment: can you look at `vector.h` for VS2010 vs the one for VS2012? The 2012 version appears to always use `unsigned int` as underlying storage type, which AFAIK is 32-bit. The statement to look for is `typedef unsigned int _Vbase; // word type for vector<bool> representation`.

Comment: @rhalbersma I tested `vector<int>` too - see my edited question, so I don't think it's a culprit.

Comment: @rhalbersma: `_Vbase` - the underlying storage type for `vector<bool>` - is `unsigned int` in both VS2010 and VS2010 (for either 64-bit or 32-bit targets).

Comment: @James McNellis I just added some complexity to the code snippet and performance magically improved (see edited question). It seems that optimizer is somewhat unstable.

Comment: @PaulJurczak:  Well, yes.  Optimizers and code generators aren't perfect.  Small changes to any piece of code may produce large changes to the generated code (and the performance thereof).

Answer (score 37):

`std::vector<bool>` is not directly at fault here.  The performance difference is ultimately caused by your use of the signed 32-bit `int` type in your loops and some rather poor register allocation by the compiler.  Consider, for example, your innermost loop:

```
for (int j = i*i; j <= n; j += i)
    isPrime[j] = false;
```

Here, `j` is a 32-bit signed integer.  When it is used in `isPrime[j]`, however, it must be promoted (and sign-extended) to a 64-bit integer, in order to perform the subscript computation.  The compiler can't just treat `j` as a 64-bit value, because that would change the behavior of the loop (e.g. if `n` is negative).  The compiler also can't perform the index computation using the 32-bit quantity `j`, because that would change the behavior of that expression (e.g. if `j` is negative).

So, the compiler needs to generate code for the loop using a 32-bit `j` then it must generate code to convert that `j` to a 64-bit integer for the subscript computation.  It has to do the same thing for the outer loop with `i`.  Unfortunately, it looks like the compiler allocates registers rather poorly in this case<sup>(*)</sup>--it starts spilling temporaries to the stack, causing the performance hit you see.

If you change your program to use `size_t` everywhere (which is 32-bit on x86 and 64-bit on x64), you will observe that the performance is on par with x86, because the generated code needs only work with values of one size:

```
Sieve (size_t n = 1)
{
    isPrime.assign (n+1, true);
    isPrime[0] = isPrime[1] = false;

    for (size_t i = 2; i <= static_cast<size_t>(sqrt((double)n)); ++i)
        if (isPrime[i]) 
            for (size_t j = i*i; j <= n; j += i)
                isPrime[j] = false;
}
```

You should do this anyway, because mixing signed and unsigned types, especially when those types are of different widths, is perilous and can lead to unexpected errors.

Note that using `std::vector<char>` also "solves" the problem, but for a different reason:  the subscript computation required for accessing an element of a `std::vector<char>` is substantially simpler than that for accessing an element of `std::vector<bool>`.  The optimizer is able to generate better code for the simpler computations.

---

(*)  I don't work on code generation, and I'm hardly an expert in either assembly or low-level performance optimization, but from looking at the generated code, and given that it is reported here that Visual C++ 2010 generates better code, I'd guess that there are opportunities for improvement in the compiler.  I'll make sure the Connect bug you opened gets forwarded on to the compiler team so they can take a look.

Comment: I had at least 3 moments throughout the answer where I wanted to upvote. Sadly, not all of them appear to have worked :)

Comment: @James McNellis Thank for your analysis. Indeed, using `size_t` makes it faster than 32-bit version. The question however remains, why VS2010 compiler was able to handle indexing much more efficiently? I tend not to use `size_t` because of this case: `for (size_t i = v.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)`.

Comment: @James McNellis I also went back to VS2010 case and 64-bit performance is the same for `int`, `size_t` and `long long`. So the compiler can handle various index types quite well.

Comment: I love answers like this. It also makes a lot of sense. @PaulJurczak if `size_t` is an issue in the case you mentioned I don't think using `int` actually solves the problem. You can't ever be sure of that code without doing a check for `v.size() == 0` first, surely?

Comment: @Matthew Walton If `v.size() == 0` then `i = -1` so condition `i >= 0` is false - I see no problem here. My case goes into infinite loop for non-zero size. `size_t` is useless for indexing in reverse.

Comment: @PaulJurczak *"`size_t` is useless for indexing in reverse"* - That's what the good old *"downto operator"* exists for: `i = v.size(); i --> 0;` (but Ok, how far this is actually cleaner is indeed controversial).

Comment: "The compiler can't just treat j as a 64-bit value, because that would change the behavior of the loop (e.g. if n is negative).". Actually, it can. Signed int overflow is UB, and therefore the optimizer can safely assume that `int j = i*i; ... j+=i` is non-negative. If `n` is negative, `j<=n` is always `false`.

Comment: @Christian Rau Upvote for mentioning `-->`. It is seriously wicked, attracting and repulsing at the same time :-)

Comment: @PaulJurczak okay, fair enough. But the fact remains that the index type is not `int`.

Comment: There is a "signed `size_t`" called something like `ptr_diff_t`?

Comment: @MSalters: Oh. It appears that the code that is posted in the question and the code that was attached to the Connect bug are different, and I was looking at the Connect bug version when writing most of this answer. In the program attached to the Connect bug, `i` is `long long`, not `int`, so in expressions involving `i`, `j` is promoted to `long long` and the result is then demoted back to `int`.  That demotion has implementation-defined behavior, not undefined behavior (Visual C++ truncates by dropping the most significant bits).

Comment: @MSalters:  I'll update the answer to better match the code posted in the question.  But first, I need to take another look through the assembly and compare with the code generated by Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: @PaulJurczak:  Looking at the code generated by Visual C++ 2010 SP1, it just generates better code:  it manages to keep everything in registers, so it avoids the performance hit caused by spilling to the stack (I've only briefly glanced at the generated code, so I'm not yet sure what differences there are in how registers are used).

Comment: @PaulJurczak:  With respect to usage of `size_t`:  `for (size_t i = v.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; --i)` has well-defined behavior to count from `size() - 1` to `0`.  Alternatively, loops involving iterators are often more intuitive (and are in many cases preferable, as they make it easier to replace loops with Standard Library algorithms).

Comment: @James McNellis `for (size_t i = v.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; --i)`  - not very pretty, but I can live with it, especially in 64-bit world where `v.size()` is much smaller than maximum value of `size_t` ;-)

Comment: @Paul : `-->` was something of a pun; Christian's code is equivalent to `i = v.size(); i--;`.

Comment: @PaulJurczak:  Even if `v.size()` is `SIZE_MAX`, the loop still works because it starts from `v.size() - 1` (so, `SIZE_MAX - 1`) and iterates until it rolls over and becomes `SIZE_MAX`, which is equivalent to `(size_t)-1`.

Comment: To me `for (size_t i = v.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; --i)` looks significantly noisier than `for (size_t i = v.size(); i--;)` – I don't see the advantage, what am I missing?

Comment: @ildjarn `for (size_t i = v.size(); i--;)` is shorter, but introduces a new weird pattern. Nice thing about `for (size_t i = v.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; --i)` is its more universal pattern. I like replacing `<` with `!=`, which works both for loops with indexes and iterators.

Comment: @Paul : It's only weird the first time you see it, after that it's idiomatic, since it works with any unsigned type and without casts. :-]

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I just run into another "anti" `size_t` case: `for (size_t i = 0; i != v.size()-N; ++i)`, which fails for vectors shorter than N-1. If you want to express Python like range (`v[0:-N]` in this case), then signed integers seem to be the most convenient.

Comment: @PaulJurczak: The correct iteration in that case will be `for (size_t i = 0; i + N < v.size(); ++i)`. Use only addition, not subtraction with unsigned types.

Answer (score 2):

`vector<bool>` is a very special container that's specialized to use 1 bit per item rather than providing normal container semantics. I suspect that the bit manipulation logic is much more expensive when compiling 64 bits (either it still uses 32 bit chunks to hold the bits or some other reason). `vector<char>` behaves just like a normal `vector` so there's no special logic.

You could also use `deque<bool>` which doesn't have the specialization.

Comment: Answer by Wouter Huysentruit below contradicts this theory.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding `std::deque` if you are using Visual C++ because it uses a very small block size.  For more information, see [an answer I gave to another question.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607710/151292)